# Hash default value not being used

Tags: ruby, hash, default-value

Today I tried the following snippets of code and I don't understand why I get different results between them. As far as I can understand they are the same.

One uses the default value off `Hash` and the other snippet creates an empty array for the key before it'll be accessed.

Anyone who understands what's going on? :)

```
# Hash default if the key doesn't have a value set is an empty Array
a = Hash.new([])
a[:key] << 2 # => [2]
p a # => {} nil
p a[:key] # => [2]
p a.keys # => []
p a.values # => []

# Explicitly add an array for all nodes before creating
b = Hash.new
b[:key] ||= []
b[:key] << 2 # => [2]
p b # => {:key=>[2]}
p b.keys # => [:key]
```

Ruby version 1.8.7

Comment: I had the same question a while ago:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552579/ruby-method-array-not-updating-the-array-in-hash

Comment: I don't think they are the same. If I try it with a block, as you did, I can't see the value I put in with `p a[:key]`. But with the default not being a block I do get the value, but it doesn't show unless I call the specific key. With `a.keys` or `a.value` I get an empty `Array` back.

Seems like a way to add secret keys to a `Hash`, for whatever reason that'd be good.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly the same. You have changed the default value (try to print `a[:foo]` in your first example and you'll see). I always start with an empty array. BTW, I have asked also this one, seems even more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822021/why-does-hash-new-hide-hash-members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you did `a[:key] << 2`, you slipped that empty array default value out and added 2 to it (modifying the actual array, not the reference) without letting the hash object `a` know that you had changed anything. You modified the object that `a` was using as a default, so you will see this as well:

```
p a[:wat] #=> [2]
p a[:anything] #=> [2]
```

In the second example, you made a new array, and use `b[:key]=` which tells `b` that it has a value under that key.

Try this if you want the best of both worlds:

```
c = Hash.new([])
c[:key] += [2]
```

This will access `c[:key]` and make a new array with `+` and reassign it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help:

```
a = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
a[:key] << 2 # => [2]
a[:key]      # => [2]
p a          # => {:key=>[2]}
```