# Ruby Hash Weirdness. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Tags: ruby, hash

After playing with with creating some new hash values I came across this Ruby weirdness... can anyone explain what is happening?

```
irb(main):001:0> some_hash = Hash.new({})
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> some_hash[:foo][:bar] = :baz
=> :baz
irb(main):003:0> some_hash
=> {}
irb(main):004:0> some_hash.keys
=> []
irb(main):005:0> some_hash[:foo]
=> {:bar=>:baz}
irb(main):006:0> some_hash.size
=> 0
irb(main):007:0> some_hash[:some_completely_new_key]
=> {:bar=>:baz}
```

Comment: I am kinda disagree, that the answer is exactly the same, since it involves “strange disappearing of `:foo` key,” which is not covered by the answer linked.

Comment: The glitch is here: `some_hash[:foo][:bar] = :baz`. You _did not assign the value_ of `some_hash[:foo]`. Call to `some_hash[:foo]` returned a default for this hash, you updated this hash successfully, but the initial hash was never updated, e. g. `some_hash#[]=` was never called. `some_hash[:foo]` in line 5 again returned the default, not the [inexisting] value of key `:foo` of `some_hash`.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822021/why-does-hash-new-hide-hash-members It covers the disappearance issue, and yet it's marked as a duplicate of a _later_ question. Weird. :)

Comment: @MladenJablanović the latter link makes much more sense, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, come up with a title that explains what the question is about. "Ruby Hash Weirdness. Can someone tell me what's going on here?" isn't very useful. Read "[ask]" and the "Question title" section of http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints, well, read all that article too as it's very good information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you think of a better title for this Ruby Hash Weirdness as an example? I'd be very grateful for the advise from such an esteemed member of the community.